# Using numpy broadcasting with scipy truncnorm

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting

I want to evaluate a one-sided truncated normal distribution for different values of the quantile and different values of the untruncated mean. For efficiency, I want to use `numpy` broadcasting rather than a Python loop.

For a minimum reproducible example, imagine the three quantiles I want to evaluate are `[3.0, 2.0, 1.0]`, the corresponding untruncated mean values are `[6.0, 5.0, 4.0]`, the lower cut-off is at `1.5`, and the untruncated standard deviation is `3.0`.

Evaluating these individually works as expected. If I run

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
print truncnorm.logpdf(3.0, a=(1.5-6.0)/3.0, b=np.inf, loc=6.0, scale=3.0)
print truncnorm.logpdf(2.0, a=(1.5-5.0)/3.0, b=np.inf, loc=5.0, scale=3.0)
print truncnorm.logpdf(1.0, a=(1.5-4.0)/3.0, b=np.inf, loc=4.0, scale=3.0)
```

I get

```
-2.44840736626
-2.3878150686
-inf
```

(The last value is `-inf` because `1.0` is less than the cut-off). Using `numpy` broadcasting for two values at a time also works as expected. If I run

```
print truncnorm.logpdf(
    np.array([3.0, 2.0]),
    a=(1.5-np.array([6.0, 5.0]))/3.0,
    b=np.inf,
    loc=np.array([6.0, 5.0]),
    scale=3.0
)
print truncnorm.logpdf(
    np.array([2.0, 1.0]),
    a=(1.5-np.array([5.0, 4.0]))/3.0,
    b=np.inf,
    loc=np.array([5.0, 4.0]),
    scale=3.0
)
```

I get

```
[-2.44840737 -2.38781507]
[-2.38781507        -inf]
```

However, if I try to evaluate three values at a time by running:

```
print truncnorm.logpdf(
    np.array([3.0, 2.0, 1.0]),
    a=(1.5-np.array([6.0, 5.0, 4.0]))/3.0,
    b=np.inf,
    loc=np.array([6.0, 5.0, 4.0]),
    scale=3.0
)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "truncnorm_error.py", line 25, in <module>
    scale=3.0
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1701, in logpdf
    place(output, cond, self._logpdf(*goodargs) - log(scale))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_continuous_distns.py", line 4853, in _logpdf
    return _norm_logpdf(x) - self._logdelta
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

What am I missing? I'm using Python 2.7, `numpy` 1.13, and `scipy` 0.19.

Comment: Looks like a bug.  You can create an issue for this at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues (hit the big green "New issue" button).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work, because `logpdf` checks the quantiles to make sure that they are larger than the cutoff. If you have a value less than the truncation, apparently it works for sizes 1 and 2, but not for 3. So this may be the bug.

If you provide values that are larger than the truncation, it works fine. For example, this works, where I changed 1.0 to 1.6 for the quantiles:

```
print truncnorm.logpdf(
    np.array([3.0, 2.0, 1.6]),
    a=(1.5-np.array([6.0, 5.0, 4.0]))/3.0,
    b=np.inf,
    loc=np.array([6.0, 5.0, 4.0]),
    scale=3.0)
```

Comment: Yes. I found the same thing. The behavior is triggered for vector lengths larger than 2 when one of the quantiles falls below the cut-off. However, I don't really want to add additional logic to my own code to handle the cut-off (because it will add computational overhead) and it's strange that the behavior only occurs for vector lengths larger than 2.

Comment: Looking at the `scipy` code, it looks like the function `logpdf` fills out its output vector with `-inf`, and only computes the values which are within the truncation range. When you have a scalar, it returns directly. If you have an array with values both within range and outside range, it has a function that picks the values within range. Apparently somehow this function messes up when the array size is larger than two.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, all. In the meantime, I rolled my own:

```
def left_truncnorm_logpdf(x, untruncated_mean, untruncated_std_dev, left_cutoff):
    f = np.array(np.subtract(stats.norm.logpdf(x, loc=untruncated_mean, scale=untruncated_std_dev),
                             np.log(1 - stats.norm.cdf(left_cutoff, loc=untruncated_mean, scale=untruncated_std_dev))))
    f[x < left_cutoff] = -np.inf
    return f
```

It's inelegant and I'm sure it has issues, but it seems to work for my purposes (e.g., it correctly broadcasts vector arguments for `x` and `untruncated_mean`).